# Stata: How do I replace missing values with a non-missing value within a cluster?

Tags: dataset, stata

I have a dataset where users report health symptoms once per week. Users can also opt to report for other members of their households. The data come in a `Users` file and a `Household` file and are linked by `user_id`. The household members are missing values for `state` and `zip`. I am struggling to find a way to populate these missing values from the data of the primary user reporting for them.

Essentially I want to say: if `state` variable is blank, populate with the data from the reporting user whose `user_id` variable is the same.

I had found a post that mentioned the `xfill` command (http://www.sealedenvelope.com/stata/xfill/) which I thought would address my needs, but I continually get an error `state is not constant within user_id`. I've had no luck researching this error to determine why it is occurring.

Can anyone explain why `xfill` does not work, or suggest an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably this is happening because you have users who move across states, while `xfill` only works for **static** variables. To verify this is the case, tag them like this:

```
capture ssc install egenmore
bys user_id: egen states = nvals(state)
edit if states>1
```

This will show you users who report living in more than one state.

If you have a date of report variable, you might be able to use `carryforward` to deal with this like this:

```
bys user_id (report_date): carryforward state, gen(state2)
```

Comment: Note that `carryforward` must also be installed from SSC before you can use it. An FAQ that might help, and which uses only official Stata commands, is at http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/

Comment: `mipolate, groupwise` is now another way to do this. http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1308786-mipolate-now-available-from-ssc-new-program-for-interpolation